# Warning message: In 1:5:length(N) : numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used

Tags: r

I am trying to separate the data to 55 time series as my assignment mentioned. My professor showed my how to separate them by crating a loop. In this case, D has 11 levels and N has 5 levels. Somehow I can only get one time series. I do not know what I should do to separate the rest of them. Anyone has an idea?

```
D=unique(T$daypart)
D
N=unique(T$network)
N

for (i in 1:length(D)) {
 for(j in 1: length(N)) {
   my_ts <- filter(T,network==N[j],daypart==D[i])
```

Comment: I formatted your code as best as I could, but there are some pretty obvious typos (missing }).

Comment: Looks like you are writing every combination of i and j into the same variable. Each time you overwrite the previous value. Use a data structure that will give each different result its own location. (maybe a list? But it depends on what you want to do next)

Answer (score 0):

Like @steveLangsford said you are overwriting your data continually. Store each run into a empty list so you can access them after it is all over:

```
##create an empty list
my_ts <- list()

##start an iteration #
iter <- 1

##feed the data in
for (i in 1:length(D)) {
 for(j in 1: length(N)) {
   my_ts[[iter]] <- filter(T,network==N[j],daypart==D[i])
   iter <- iter + 1
}
}
```